# Can I make a package .deb from .tar.gz or .tar.bz2?

Tags: packaging, deb, tar

If I had an application with `.tar.gz` or `.tar.bz2` extension can I transform it to a `package .deb` ?

Comment: Although I marked this as a duplicate, nothing really replaces learning to make a proper .deb + 1 , see the packaging guideline or ppa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use checkinstall for that create deb from tar.gz or bz2

**How to use**

1. Extract your tar.gz to a folder.
2. Go to folder
3. If there is not makefile , create
4. Type `sudo checkinstall`.

Package will be created there

See the complete documentation at [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall).

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You are prbably better off extracting it and using one of the tools to make a proper deb.

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/162 Works quite well.

That said it is possible to create a .deb containing your .tar.gz and have a post install script extract it, but that is mostly pointless.